# Problems wuth authorisation with Vue 3 and Firebase

Tags: firebase, vuejs3

I am trying to make authorisation form for my project. But I think i dont have connection with firebase due to some mistakes in me code or maybe i just didnt write some important thing
I used some code from firebase doc, code from other soursec doesnt word at all on current versions of vue and firebase...

main.js:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import store from './store'
import router from './router'
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyB47Sb1R97QKdWzF8B6LXg-SDyxj_feAzY",
    authDomain: "vue-diploma.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "vue-diploma",
    storageBucket: "vue-diploma.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "888817849951",
    appId: "1:888817849951:web:eba6fd0821a5734205adea",
    measurementId: "G-MG2HZQ1JLY"
  };
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
createApp(App).use(router).use(store).mount('#app')
```

In login component i ve got this import for firebase
`import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";`

I ve got this code in methods

```
  methods: {
     async onSubmit () {
      this.v$.$touch();
      if (this.v$.$error) return;
      const formData = {
      email: this.email,
      password: this.password,
      name: this.name  
     }
     const auth = getAuth();
     try{
     signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, formData)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    const user = userCredential.user;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
  });
     this.$router.push('/') 
    } catch (error) 
     {
      
     }
    },
    capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
      return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
    },
  },
```

I recieve email and login from input and dont see any mistakes in that part, how ever when i click on button lof in and I call doing this onSubmit function I recieve in console an error 400:
terialize.min.css   Fetchaccounts:signInWithPassword?key=AIzaSyB47Sb1R97QKdWzF8B6LXg-SDyxj_feAzY
{error: {code: 400, message: "Invalid value (email), Starting an object on a scalar field",…}}
error
:
{code: 400, message: "Invalid value (email), Starting an object on a scalar field",…}
code
:
400
details
:
[{@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",…}]
0
:
{@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",…}
errors
:
[{message: "Invalid value (email), Starting an object on a scalar field", reason: "invalid"}]
0
:
{message: "Invalid value (email), Starting an object on a scalar field", reason: "invalid"}
message
:
"Invalid value (email), Starting an object on a scalar field"
status
:
"INVALID_ARGUMENT"
I've created a User in firebase intarface beforehand
And I beleive that i have thar erroe because i do not connecting with firebase, but i dont know why
How evere if i remove "auth" grom here `signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, formData)` i will not receive that mistake, but i still think that it doesnt work properly because i ve got same behaviour in my SignUp component
Here code related to SignUp...

```
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
//////////////////////////////////////////////
 methods: {
   async onSubmit () {
      this.v$.$touch();
      if (this.v$.$error) return;
      const formData = {
      email: this.email,
      password: this.password,
      name: this.name  
     }
     const auth = getAuth();
     try{
     createUserWithEmailAndPassword(formData)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    const user = userCredential.user;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
  });
     } catch (error) 
     {
      
     }
     this.$router.push('/') 
    
    },
    capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
      return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
    },
  },
```

I'll be grateful for help